# Apple Cinema Display - Doesn't work if USB plugged in

Tags: usb, display, power

**Product**

Apple 30" Cinema display ('05)

**Scenario**

For my macbook pro laptop this monitor requires a mini display port + usb connection to provide full resolution of 2560x1600. However with my desktop PC (gtx 1080) it only requires a display port connection BUT having the USB features on the monitor is a nice accessory.

The display works with just the miniDP -> DisplayPort adapter but whenever I attempt to plug in the associated usb the monitor goes blank and becomes unresponsive (blank, no power light). It used to be roughly 1/10 tries the usb would work but lately it's been more like 1/50 - not consecutive attempts but over days, weeks, etc (trying one day, trying again the next day, etc etc). When usb DOES work it continues to work until I unplug the usb from the PC. A restart of the computer is fine however an unplug for a short time seems to reset the whole process; It's a very finicky issue.

**Question**

What can I do to fix and/or troubleshoot the issue further ?

** EDIT **

For those willing I would also be curious to hear your theory in the comments as to why this USB connection can sometimes be made. My rather unscientific explanation is my neighbor's cat died recently and their ghost playing with the wires inside my monitor. JK it seems heat related eg when the monitor is warm a USB connection seems more likely to be made.

But for real, that cat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely sounds like the USB controller on the monitor is bad.  Since it is so old, it is very likely out of warranty.  Can it be repaired?  Possibly.  Your best bet is to find an electronics repair shop that specializes in Apple hardware.  They are the most likely to have replacement parts on hand, or know where to get them.  If you are lucky, this is a replaceable module.  If not, it might be able to be fixed with some board level work.  However, be sure to check the price of the repairs beforehand, as the cost might not be worthwhile.